# register with email confirmation and set as blocked or disabled while an admin user approve him

Tags: node.js, loopback

I'm setting up a system and I want to select the best framework, so, using loopback, I want to have the approval functionality like drupal, when any user signing up, they must validate her email and wait for some administrator approve them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this requirement you need to override the method of login/signin which loopback provides in user model and then you have to validate whether admin has approved the account of user or not.